# How to prove that $n=2^k$?

Tags: number-theory

Let two collection $\{a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n}\}\neq\{b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n}\}$ and $a_{i},b_{i}\in\Bbb Q$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n $ be such that
$$\{a_{i}+a_{j}\mid1\le i<j\le n\}=\{b_{i}+b_{j}\mid1\le i<j\le n\}\;.$$
Show that
$n=2^k$ for some $k\in\Bbb N$.

This problem was asked by my friend. Thank you.

And I know that for $n=2$ the sets $\{1,4\}$ and $\{2,3\}$ have this property.
[image]

Comment: Bill Gasarch just posted a very nice proof of this (of unknown origin) on his [blog](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2013/07/another-nice-use-of-gen-functions.html).

Comment: oh,Thank you.!it's nice